# How do I constrain filesize of a bunch of photos?

Tags: photoshop, batch, file-size, adobe-bridge

I have a bunch of photos of jewelry that I need to upload to a website. Unfortunately there is a 2MB file size limit. Most of the photos are JPEGs over 3MB.

I want to keep the aspect ratio, meta data, and highest quality possible at under 2MB. Adobe Bridge will allow me to set an image size limit when I export, but not the file size.

Does anyone know of a way to render the images with a max filesize limit?

Comment: Alex, is doing this in Bridge your desired approach (even if the answer is "sorry, no luck"), or are you open to solutions which require a software switch?

Comment: The problem is that, with JPEGs, you don't control the file size directly. You can set the number of pixels, or the JPEG "quality" which in turn affect the file size. I use Irfanview to change image size. It's free, and can be run in batch mode.The problem is that, with JPEGs, you don't control the file size directly. You can set the number of pixels, or the JPEG "quality" which in turn affect the file size. I use Irfanview to change image size. It's free, and can be run in batch mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe Bridge has this functionality.

Photoshop and Lightroom (with a mogrify plugin) have this ability to set a file size based export.

Answer (score 2):

Lightroom 3 has the built-in ability to set a filesize constraint when exporting.
I haven't used it myself, and I'm aware there has been the odd bug related to that functionality, but it definitely exists.

Comment: I have used it; it works perfectly fine. You can also set the limit in different publishing services (hard-drive, facebook, flickr and smugmug support out of box)

Answer (score 0):

If you are shooting for a website that limits your file size, just shoot the photos with that website in mind. Preset your camera with that size photo. IE an 800x600 or a 640x480. But if your camera will not do this, then a resizing program (like those mentioned) will have to be used.

Answer (score 0):

Use FastStone image viewer. You can convert files in a batch. (Multiple files at once)
The aspect ratio is maintained.

http://www.faststone.org/download.htm

Answer (score 0):

In Adobe Bridge, you can do the batch image processing by going to Tools -> Photoshop -> Image Processor... (You need Photoshop installed).
Then select the location to save and resize the photos as you wish. It won't give you the option to select the file size, but you can apply the right Quality, so with trial and error you will know which Quality you need to set to expect the specific image size.

**OSX**

Or if you've access to the terminal you can do: `sips -Z 1024 *.jpg` (make the backup first, if you want to preserve images with their larger size).

Also there is easy way of resizing the images using Preview. Select a group of images and open them all with the Preview App. Once they are opened in Preview, Select All, either by hitting ⌘+A (Command+A) or by clicking the Edit menu and select that option. Then go to Tools -> Adjust Size, enter a value for the new width and height, then hit OK. Go to File and click Save All or to save a NEW resized version, choose Export Selected Images or just Save As.